# SELECT records with date in format 'YYYY-MM' into given range

Tags: mysql, date, between

I want to fetch all the products which are near to "*expire*".

Date format on expiry date column `exDate` is `(Y-m)` or `YYYY-MM`, for example: `2018-03`.

I am trying with this query but it fetches all record from the table.

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE (exDate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'Y-m') AND NOW()+ interval 2 month)
```

Comment: That looks like invalid SQL. What's the column type of `exDate`? If it is `DATE` or something like that, you should not use `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: exDate coiumn  is varchar where to use DATE_FORMAT i have already used it in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `exDate` from the `YYYY-MM` format into the mySql **date** format `YYYY-MM-DD` then perform the query on that value:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE STR_TO_DATE( `exDate`, "%Y-%m" ) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

---

Take `exDate` and turn into mySql **date** format `YYYY-MM-DD` with

```
STR_TO_DATE( `exDate`, "%Y-%m" )
```

Note the `%` symbol is needed to specify the format.

Then this is the value that must fall into the interval.

Note you can just use `CURDATE()` to get the current date into **date** format.

To add a time interval to a **date** you have to use the mySql function `DATE_ADD()`

---

Note that as of today `2018-03-17` you will catch products with `exDate` with values `2018-04` and `2018-05`.

`2018-03` **is not** part of the results as it's turned into `2018-03-01` and is **before** today (the lower limit).

`2018-05` **is** part of the results because it's turned into `2018-05-01` and is before the upper limit `DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)` that evaluates to `2018-05-17`

Comment: thank you for your answer @Paolo But the result is 0 now

Comment: i checked it but still not getting the result

Comment: then you don't have any `product` with `exDate` falling into the interval. Running the query today `2018-03-17` will catch any product with `exDate` with value `2018-04` or  `2018-05`. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: i have checked it again and its working perfectly thanks alot @Paolo

Comment: Thanks Again Mr.Paolo for giving your precious time.